# Yarn fails incorrectly reporting incompatible node version

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, yarnpkg, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to run `yarn` command in my project, but it fails, reporting incompatible Node version.

The weird thing is that my version of `node` is `12.7.0`, not `13.0.0-nightly2019072543e5478e2f` as reported by Yarn`.

What's going on?

*Note*: I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, which has outdated Node version, but I updated it to 12.7.0 using NVM.

### Commands output

#### `$ yarn`

```sh
yarn install v1.17.3
warning You are using Node "13.0.0-nightly2019072543e5478e2f" which is not supported and may encounter bugs or unexpected behavior. Yarn supports the following semver range: "^4.8.0 || ^5.7.0 || ^6.2.2 || >=8.0.0"
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error xmlbuilder@9.0.7: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=4.0". Got "13.0.0-nightly2019072543e5478e2f"
error Found incompatible module.
```

#### `$ node --version`

```sh
v12.7.0
```

#### `$ nvm list`

```sh
        v12.6.0
->      v12.7.0
         system
default -> node (-> v12.7.0)
node -> stable (-> v12.7.0) (default)
stable -> 12.7 (-> v12.7.0) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/dubnium (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.16.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.16.0 (-> N/A)
```

Comment: Did you try to reinstall node?

Comment: @GProst: I tried reinstalling bothh using NVM and Ubuntu's package manager. Didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this issue as well with the following output:

`The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^12.1.0". Got "14.18.0"`

In my `package.json`, I found:   `"engines": { "node": "^12.1.0", "npm": ">= 5" }`

I installed the n package manager using `npm install -g n`. Note that n only works on Linux/MacOS. Windows can use NVM to achieve the same end.
I then ran `n 12.1.0` and this installed Node version 12.1.0 and Yarn is happy now.

https://blog.logrocket.com/switching-between-node-versions-during-development/ - instructions about changing Node versions.